# Quelle serait une façon plus correcte de dire: « Ils m’ont passé en entrevue »

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Contexte:

Bonjour,

Je tiens par la présente à vous confirmer que M. Untel et Mme Unetelle m’ont passé en entrevue à l’occasion de leur projet de fin d’études dans le but d’en connaître davantage sur mon métier.

Anglicismes à proscrire: interviewer, interview.

Comment: Je vous confirme que j'ai eu un entretien avec M. Untel et Mme Untelle. Cet entretien avait pour but de leur permettre de mieux connaître mon métier dans le cadre de leur projet de fin d'étude.

Comment: Interview/interviewer sont intégrés au vocabulaire français depuis un moment, mais seraient néanmoins inadaptés ici, puisqu'il ne s'agit pas de journalistes.

Comment: @jlliagre  A la cinquième lecture, oui. Le OP écrit à quelqu'un pour lui dire que deux étudiants l'ont interviewé dans le cadre de LEUR projet pour se renseigner sur son métier à lui. Et les deux étudiants ont besoin de la lettre comme preuve de l'entretien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Je vous confirme par la présente que j'ai accordé un entretien à M. Untel et Mme Unetelle afin de leur en faire connaître davantage sur mon métier, ceci dans le cadre de leur projet de fin d’études.

A la place de *j'ai accordé un entretien à*, on pourrait aussi dire *j'ai reçu (en entretien/rendez-vous)* ou le moins protocolaire *j'ai rencontré*. Merci @XouDo pour son commentaire.

PS: Dommage que @Denis ait répondu en commentaire et pas dans une réponse...

Comment: Pas de problème : content d'avoir pu aider un peu.

Comment: *accordé un entretien* : je valide ! On aurait aussi pu dire : je les ai reçu en entretien/rendez-vous, je les ai rencontrés dans le cadre de leur projet de fin d'étude.

Comment: @ Xoudou « Je les ai reçus en entrevue », je l’adopte! J’hésite si « je les ai soumis à une entrevue » dénote un sens péjoratif ou pourrait être pris défavorablement?

Comment: Il est des gens qui entendent finesse à tout…

Comment: *Je les ai soumis à une entrevue* laisse supposer que cette entrevue était une épreuve, quelque chose de désagréable ou difficile.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour le complément d'information!

Answer (score 0):

*Le verbe  « consacrer », plutôt formel, pourrait être utilisé. On peut aussi choisir d'exprimer l'idée de but de façon moins explicite, mais, bien sûr,  ce choix n'est pas une question de style de langage ni même nécesairement la marque d'une expression plus raffinée (j'ajoute quand même une modification illustrant cette seconde remarque).*

- Je tiens par la présente à vous confirmer qu'en rapport avec leur projet de fin d’études, j'ai consacré à M. Untel et Mme Unetelle  une entrevue dont le but était d'en connaître davantage sur mon métier.
- Je tiens par la présente à vous confirmer qu'en rapport avec leur projet de fin d’études, j'ai consacré à M. Untel et Mme Unetelle  une entrevue  au cours de laquelle ils se sont efforcés d'en connaître davantage sur mon métier.

([réf. 2011](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Moments_m%C3%A9morables_d_un_Chemin_de_Saint/Vuu0CwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22consacr%C3%A9+un+long%22&pg=PA111&printsec=frontcover)) Chacune des statues prises individuellement mériterait que l'on lui consacre un long moment.

([réf. 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_vieux/w2QhEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22consacr%C3%A9+un+long%22&pg=PT82&printsec=frontcover)) .. Simon a consacré un long moment à écrire dans le cahier noir qu'il trimballait toujours.

Comment: C'est "moi" qui ai consacré une entrevue aux étudiants plutôt que l'inverse.

Comment: @jlliagre M. et Mme Untel sont ceux qui agissent en ce qui concerne l'entrevue ; s'ils « passent la  personne en entrevue  », quel que soit l'idiomaticité de cette expression (je la trouve très peu idiomatique), il est quand même évident que ceux qui accordent l'entrevue sont M. et Mme Untel. De plus rien ne dit que ce sont des étudiants ; en fait ils sont très probablement des responsables d'étude qui examninent un titulaire d'un diplôme d'enseignement, dans le cadre de leur projet d'une offre d'étude.

Comment: Hou là ! Le moins qu'on puisse dire est que nous ne comprenons pas la même chose à la phrase de la question et au sens de l'expression "consacrer une entrevue"...

Comment: @jlliagre Le contexte de deux étudiants qui soumettraient leur éducateur à des vérifications de compétence ne peut  se trouver que dans un domaine  assez spécial de l'enseignement, celui des particuliers qui peuvent se permettre un tuteur privé. C'est toutefois possible.

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te fait penser que la personne qui parle est un "éducateur" ? Où as-tu vu qu'il y a une offre d'étude ? Qu'est-ce qui te fait douter qu'il s'agit d'étudiants ?

Comment: @jlliagre Comment est-on sûr de ce qu'est ce projet de fin d'étude ? Il peut s'agir d'une étude par des ingénieurs à la fin de laquelle un projet est considéré, soit le le projet auquel aboutissent les études, soit un projet de plus. c'est encore une possibilité, mais la formulation que je j'utilise y correspond.

Comment: *[Projet de fin d'études](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet_de_fin_d%27%C3%A9tudes)* est une expression clairement définie qui décrit un travail effectué par des étudiants pour achever leurs études. Le projets de fin d'études ne se font jamais dans un organisme d'enseignement, donc la personne ne peut pas être un enseignant.